# PyInstaller not recognized even after adding scripts to my environment variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pyinstaller

I attempted to download PyInstaller through pip and then use it to compile a *.py file I made. It doesn't run, instead, it gives me the `"'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."` error. Even after modifying my PATH variables to include the Scripts path. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused/fixed by a few possible things:

- If you make modifications to your `PATH`, you'll have to reopen your command prompt for the changes to take effect.
- If you have multiple versions of Python installed, you'll have multiple `Scripts/` folders, so make sure the Python version you want is not only in the `PATH`, but also appears in the `PATH` before any other Python version installed.

Path modification steps for Windows:

- From the desktop Start Menu, search for "environment variables" (will be in the Control Panel). In the "System Properties" window, click on the "Advanced" tab.
  In the "Advanced" tab, click the "Environment Variables..." button.
  Search for the "Path" variable under the "Systems variables" section and click the "Edit" button. Make sure the "...Scripts/" folder of the Python version you want appears at the top before any other "Scripts/" folder. Click "OK", then close/reopen any command prompts.

Comment: The Python version I'm using is 3.8, and it is at the top of the PATH variables section. Also, after installing pyinstaller, after going to scripts I don't see the pyinstaller.exe file or any of the other pyinstaller files.